# Как сделать кнопку неактивной для нажатия на некоторое время?

Tags: android, android-threads

Нужно, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку, она скрывалась на 10сек, а после была вновь доступна. Пробовал через потоки, приложение полностью зависает на некоторое время. Хелп, плиз.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так как вопрос не содержит в себе описания задачи, предлагаю следующее решение.

Простой пример в комментариях кода указаны свойства:

- **.setEnabled** - сделает кнопку *доступной/недоступной*
- **.setVisibility** - спрячет кнопку или покажет

  ```
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  private Button helloButton;

  private final Handler handler = new Handler();

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      helloButton = findViewById(R.id.buttonHello);
      helloButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
              //сделать ее не доступной
              helloButton.setEnabled(false);
              //спрятать ее
              helloButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
              handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                  @Override
                  public void run() {
                      //чтоб она была снова доступна
                      helloButton.setEnabled(true);
                      //чтоб она отображаласьь
                      helloButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                  }
              }, 10000);
          }
      });
  }
  ```

  }

А вообще нужно смотреть в сторону CallBack или RxJava.